# Negotiating the amount of a raise

Tags: salary, negotiation, raise

I am working in small scale company and our company offer a fixed entry level package. In interview I asked for a higher salary, and agreed to take the initial offer when they told me after six months they will increase it by a certain percentage, which they did (they apparently never did this for any other employee).

**Now in other part:**

At annual appraisal they gave me a raise of some percentage which, compared to what I heard from colleagues, is reduced by the amount of percent I got after six months. Also the salary is confidential so I can hardly call them out on it, or ask openly why my raise was less than that of my colleagues.

**My question is :**

Is it reasonable to negotiate on this issue and if so, how would one go about it?

Comment: @eatSleepCode I edited your question a bit, to make it easier to understand (at least for me) and also changed the focus of your question a bit, as we can't tell you what to do, but may be able to discuss why it may or may not be a good idea and how to go about it. Please feel free to roll back or [edit] some more if you're not satisfied with my changes.

Comment: Thanks @CMW This is really easy to understand and language is also good.

Comment: You should base the amount of money you want on what you think you deserve, not what others are getting. I target this at about 4%, twice a year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since appraisals and raises are done individually and you're basically the new guy in the company, do you have any evidence beyond *"others got more than I did"*, that support your assumption, your raise was reduced by what you got after 6 months?

If you do, bring it up in a matter-of-fact way, perferably in a one-on-one setting with your manager/boss. **Tell them how you see it, and why you think you deserve a bigger raise than you got.** And leave out the fact that you know what others got, because that might get you or them in trouble.

However, keep in mind, that these raises are supposed to reflect every individuals performance as well. Maybe others got bigger raises *because they're perceived as having improved their performance more than you*, or maybe even by the same amount as you did, which *forced your manager to increase their raises to stay fair in relation to the two raises that you got*.

**If there's any doubt at all**, that you might have been treated unfairly; if you're not 100% sure, **don't raise the issue**. Be happy with the raise you've received and see how this turns out in your next appraisal. If the pattern continues, you can still bring it up then.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to get the better raise next time.